# nested if condition in calculated field

Tags: workflow, calculated-column

If have a SP2010 List with all kind of productsnumbers in. Some are forbidden for some regions.

I created my list as described below:

```
Title = my productnumber
ForBiddenRegion1 = YES/NO
ForBiddenRegion2 = YES/NO
ForBiddenRegion3 = YES/NO
ForBiddenRegion4 = YES/NO
Attention = Needs to be my calculated field.
```

I'd like to have the Attention colum updated with my title if its forbidden for one or more regions. If none is set to Yes, nothing needs te be written in the collumn.

I tried it with a workflow - this works fine for 3 of 4 regions. But this list needs to be update with about 15 regions. This is no longer possible with the IF statements in te workflow.

Is their a formula i can use to update this via calculated field?

Answer (score 1):

There are similar restrictions to nested IF statements in calculated columns but in this case I do not think the nesting is necessary.

Option 1: Try using an OR statement eg:

```
=IF(OR([ForbiddenRegion1], [ForbiddenRegion2], [ForbiddenRegion3] . . . etc),[Title],"")
```

Option 2: Create a calculated column for each setting 1 or 0 then sum them eg:

```
=IF([ForbiddenRegion1],1,0)
```

etc, then:

```
=IF(SUM([FR1], [FR2], [FR3], etc) > 0, [Title], "")
```

Both of the above assume your YES/NO is a Boolean.  If not you may need to be specific about each value.

Comment: Thank you for both tips. The work fine. I'm now using the first one. For some reason, i needed to change the , in the formula to ;

Comment: Great you got it working :)